# How to pass a key to a service app through Azure application's gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-gateway

I have configured an application gateway in the Azure portal and I have added a function app in the backend pool. The authorization level on one of the function in the function app is set to "function", now I want to pass the function key of this function using application gateway instead of passing it through URL.

for example- http://20.0.0.1/api/HttpExample?code=XV2Js97D/Zy5aw6th2hr7iLzFbBiuZ4RfdKuT8nA==

Where, 20.0.0.1 is application gateway public IP and

/api/HttpExample?code=XV2Js97D/Zy5aw6th2hr7iLzFbBiuZ4RfdKuT8nA== is function URL

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: You can refer to [Azure Application Gateway for Azure Function App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76ab2147-b967-4c99-9b26-9f5f1872e869/azure-application-gateway-for-azure-function-app?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below two ways used to pass a key to function app from API and get the output without key in the URL.

**Method 1:**

Passing the Key to the service App in the form of Headers.
**Steps:**

- Azure Portal > API Management Service > Your API > Your Service App >
  Select Get HttpTrigger > Click on Test Pane
- There you can copy the key -value or you can also copy from the
  subscriptions pane in your API Service.
- Pass these values to the header section in the developer portal of
  your API, as shown below:

[image]

Then the output will be:

[image]

**Method 2:**

1. Go to Azure Portal > API Management Services > Your API > APIs pane
2. Select your service app ( I selected Function App)
3. Click on Settings > uncheck the box option 'Subscription required' on Subscription Menu and click on Save.

*Note: Make Sure you have removed the key in the headers section*.

Now run your API in developer portal, it should show 200 response code as below:
[image]

- Unchecking the subscription key in the settings menu should not be
  done on production side. It can be used for Dev and Testing Purposes.

***Passing the key to a service app in the form of header is one of the best way, instead in the URL.***